# PyroCMS assets plugin with bower_components

Tags: assets, bower, pyrocms

I want to manage my theme assets using bower.

How would I configure PyroCMS / the assets plugin to get may assets from the `bower_components` folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only for 2.1 or 2.2 version.

In your controller or base controller (maybe system/cms/core/public_controller.php) constructor, register the path for bower_components writing the next code:

```
 // Set the theme bower components as a path for Asset library
 Asset::add_path('bower', array(
     'path' => $this->theme->path.'/bower_components',
     'js_dir' => '/',
     'css_dir' => '/',
 ));
```

Use this in your views writing first the name of path:

```
{{ asset:js file="bower::jquery/dist/jquery.js" }} // For JS
{{ asset:css file="bower::bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" }} // For CSS
```

For correct read of assets you must place the bower.json and bower_components folder to your theme folder, for example:

```
addons/shared_addons/themes/your_theme/bower.json
addons/shared_addons/themes/your_theme/bower_components/
```